# Is there a limit for line length in PAM config files?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, pam

**How I got to this suspicion:**

I try to configure the proxy at my companies network. There are quite a few hosts that can only be reached without proxy, so I tried configuring `$NO_PROXY` in `/etc/environment`. However, the environment variable that is actually set seems to be cut to a certain length (inspected with `echo $NO_PROXY`).

After some fiddling I managed to set the correct variable with

```
NO_PROXY_1 DEFAULT=some,hosts
NO_PROXY_2 DEFAULT=some,more.hosts
NO_PROXY_3 DEFAULT=...
NO_PROXY_4 DEFAULT=...
...

NO_PROXY DEFAULT=${NO_PROXY_1},${NO_PROXY_2},...
```

Still, I wonder why this is necessary.

**Some more investigation:**

I could not find it documented anywhere, but I suppose the line length limit would be 1024, because `echo $no_proxy | wc` gave me 1014 characters, plus `NO_PROXY="` is 10 characters (not sure anymore about the exact numbers, but it looked like it would add up to 1024)

I'm on Manjaro Linux (which is basically Arch) with pam 1.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, the current source for [linux-pam](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam) shows both code that uses a 1024 character buffer e.g. in `modules/pam_env/pam_env.c`

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
...
_parse_config_file(pam_handle_t *pamh, int ctrl, const char *file)
{
    int retval;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
...
    while (( retval = _assemble_line(conf, buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
```

and other code that uses `getline` which has no such limit. You've probably run into a code path that uses one of the 1024 character buffers.

Also there are other PAM implementations (OpenPAM) which may again differ.